# Cannot take the address of the given expression C# pointer

Tags: c#, pointers

Consider the following code in an unsafe context:

```
string mySentence = "Pointers in C#";

fixed (char* start = mySentence) // this is the line we're talking about
{
    char* p = start;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(*p);
    }
    while (*(++p) != '\0');
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This works good.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21(v=VS.100).aspx I should be able to replace the line I marked with

```
fixed(char* start = &mySentence[0])
```

But unfortunately VS gives me the following error.

> Cannot take the address of the given expression

Is the error on my side?

VS.NET 2010 Premium.

Comment: hmmm. I don't get that error!

Comment: Word of warning, String in .Net is not guaranteed to be null terminated and it may also contain nulls. You should still use mySentence.Length

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is the error on my side?

No; the error is in the documentation you linked to.  It states:

```
fixed (char* p = str) { /*...*/ }  // equivalent to p = &str[0]
```

The comment is incorrect; as you correctly note, it is not legal to take the address of the interior of a string.  It is only legal to take the address of the interior of an array.

The legal initializers for a fixed statement are:

- The address operator `&` applied to a variable reference.
- An array
- A string
- A fixed-size buffer.

`str[0]` is not a variable reference, because first, string elements are not variables, and second, because this is a call to an indexing function, not a reference to a variable. Nor is it an array, a string, or a fixed-size buffer, so it should not be legal.

I'll have a chat with the documentation manager and we'll see if we can get this fixed in a later revision of the documentation. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

UPDATE: I have spoken to one of the documentation managers and they have informed me that we have just passed the deadline for the next scheduled revision of the documentation. The proposed change will go in the queue for the revision after next.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because you're trying to access a string. If you change your code to:

```
char[] mySentence = "Pointers in C#".ToCharArray();

fixed (char* start = &mySentence[0])
{
    char* p = start;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(*p);
    }
    while (*(++p) != '\0');
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

everything will work fine.

Comment: Isn't a string already a char array? He should be able to do that without converting.

Comment: Yes and No, but you can call the ToCharArray method on it, just to be explicit.

Comment: no because in .net string is a Managed type even in a unsafe context and so you can't take address of a managed type

Comment: "you can't take address of a managed type". Yes you can, hence the fixed block.

Comment: If a string was already a char array, what would be the point of the ToCharArray() method?  It is not, you can only pin the string, not a string element.

Comment: "Under the hood" it is, but that fact is not exposed to the outside world.

Comment: @MattDavey: I assure you that you cannot take the address of any managed type with the "fixed" statement. See section 18.6 of the specification; it clearly states that the pointer referent type must be an unmanaged type in the fixed statement. In the case of fixing a string, the unmanaged type in question is "char", not "string". **You can never obtain a pointer to a string, only to a char**.

Comment: @Eric: this might be a stupid question, but why can you not obtain a pointer to a string, but a char? Isn't string values made up of collection of chars? I imagine it's because the runtime is free to store each char of a string all over the place?

Comment: @Joan: That's a reasonable question. It's not so much that the CLR is free to store the chars all over the place; we actually do guarantee that the chars are contiguous. Rather, it's that value types contain their values, but reference types do not; the CLR wants to be free to have any strategy they choose for memory management of the internal details of reference types. Like, how is it that every object of reference type knows its type? Knows where its interface method implementations are? and so on. There are many different possible strategies for laying that information out in memory.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks Eric, I got it now. It makes sense to do that so you have all the control you need in memory management.

Answer (score 0):

mySentence[0] returns a readonly single character, you cannot get a pointer to that.

Use:

```
fixed(char* start = &mySentence)
```

instead.