# Compiler says I cannot take the address of a value type's readonly field

Tags: c#, unsafe, value-type, addressof

I have a struct:

```
struct S {
    public readonly int Value1;
    public readonly int Value2;
    public S(int value1, int value2) {
        this.Value1 = value1;
        this.Value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

and I try to take the address of Value2:

```
var s = default(S);
unsafe {
    var r = new IntPtr(&s.Value2);
}
```

but I get a compiler error:

```
Cannot take the address of the given expression
```

I thought I could take the addresses of fields? What's going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079736/cannot-take-the-address-of-the-given-expressionc-pointer

Comment: That's a similar question, but resolution is entirely different. The issue was syntactic, not semantic. Plus the only mention of `readonly` is a slightly-wrong answer which appears to be talking about the result-is-a-copy-ness rather than the readonly-ness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't work with readonly fields. Changing S to this:

```
struct S {
    public int Value1;
    public int Value2;
}
```

fixes the problem.